# Binary Vector in GF(2) to integer

Tags: sage

I am using the CAS SAGE. I have a vector v belonging GF(2). How I will be able to find the integer representation of this vector? Any example please?

```
 aux = random_matrix(GF(2), n,2*n)
 for i in range(2*n):
     x = ZZ(list(aux[:,i]), base=2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I understand you, you have a vector living in a space over GF(2):

```
sage: V = VectorSpace(GF(2), 5)
sage: V
Vector space of dimension 5 over Finite Field of size 2
sage: v = V.random_element()
sage: v
(0, 1, 0, 1, 1)
```

There are lots of ways to convert this to an `Integer`, and lots of equally valid representations.  One natural one would be:

```
sage: i = ZZ(list(v), base=2)
sage: i
26
sage: parent(i)
Integer Ring
sage: i.digits(2)
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```

Comment: I cann't get this. I edit my question with my code. The error is TypeError: unable to coerce <type 'sage.matrix.matrix_integer_dense.Matrix_integer_dense'> to an integer

Comment: @Juan: by using `aux[:,i]`, you're getting a columnar matrix, not a vector.  `print type(aux[:,i])` to convince yourself this is true.  So `list(aux[:,i])` is producing something like `[(0), (1), (1), (1), (0)]` instead of what you want.  IOW, you're one level too high up; you need a list of elements of GF(2), not a list of collections.  Try something like `ZZ(list((aux[:,i].T)[0]), 2)`.

Comment: @Juan: `.T` is simply an abbreviation for `transpose`.

Comment: thanks, and for make the inverse. Let be a "i" a integer How I will be able to get a columnar matrix?